# React: dynamic import jsx

Tags: reactjs

This question related to dynamically importing JSX files into React.

Basically we have one main component that dynamically renders other components based on a structure stored in a database. The dynamic components are stored in a subdirectory "./Components". We statically define the this as:

```
import CompA  from './Components/CompA';
import CompB  from './Components/CompB';

var components = {
 'CompA': CompA,
 'CompB': CompB
}
```

and we render them using:

```
var type = 'CompA' 
var Component = components[type];
...
<Component />
```

While this works fine, it is a bit too static for us. We have 100+ components (CompA/CompBs) and statically define them does not work.

Is it possible to import all JSX files in "./Compontents" and populate the components-array?

And, what would be really (really) nice would be if we could send the "./Components" path as a prop to the main components. And the main component would use this path to import the .jsx files. Like this:

```
<MainComponent ComponentPath="./SystemComponents">
```

Would use "./SystemComponents" as path for .JSX files and:

```
<MainComponent ComponentPath="./UserComponents">
```

Would use "./UserComponents" as import path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about having a components/index.js with contents:

```
export CompA from "./comp_a";
export CompB from "./comp_b";
```

Then you do:

```
import * as Components from "./components"
```

then you would use as:

```
<Components.CompA />
<Components.CompB />
...
```

Hope this helps.

I doubt you can load anything when sending path through component props, loading of the file should then happen inside the React component lifecycle methods which is not something I would recommend.

Comment: Nice! This solution actually works really well for us. We can import all libraries (the different paths in the example above) and pass the desired library as props. PS. For some reason I could not get the export CompA from "./comp_a" to work, had to first import them, and them export them in an json object.

Comment: @mathan one liner export is part of babel stage-1 preset : [export-extensions](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions/)

Answer (score 1):

As of [React 16.6.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html), we can [lazy-load components](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) and invoke them on-demand.

**The Routing**

```
// We pass the name of the component to load as a param
<Switch>
  …
  <Route path="/somewhere/:componentName" component={MyDynamicComponent} />
</Switch>
```

**views/index.js**

```
import { lazy } from 'react';

const SomeView = lazy(() => import('./SomeView'));
const SomeOtherView = lazy(() => import('./SomeOtherView'));

export { SomeView, SomeOtherView };
```

**MyDynamicComponent.js**

```
import React, { Suspense, Component } from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import shortid from 'shortid'; // installed separately via NPM
import * as Views from './views';

class MyDynamicComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      match: {
        params: { componentName },
      },
    } = this.props;

    const Empty = () => <div>This component does not exist.</div>;
    const dynamicComponent = (() => {
      const MyComponent = Views[`${componentName}View`]
        ? Views[`${componentName}View`]
        : Empty;
      return <MyComponent key={shortid.generate()} />;
    })();

    return (
      <>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading…</div>}>{dynamicComponent}</Suspense>
      </>
    );
  }
}
MyDynamicComponent.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      componentName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
  }),
};

export default MyDynamicComponent;
```

**Usage**

```
{items.map(item => (
  <NavLink to={`/somewhere/${item.componentName}`}>
    {item.name}
  </NavLink>
))}
```

Comment: Thanks! In your example, can I split out views/index.js to a seperate npm package? For example can it be located in another yarn workspace or npm link package?

Comment: @mathan In the separate package, create an array in containing the names of your desired components. You'll then export that array as follows: `module.exports = myArray`. In `views/index.js` import the package and loop over the exported array, interpolating the array values into the loop output. That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @gor181's answer, I can add that `export`s must be this way:

`export { default as CompA } from "./comp_a";
export { default as CompB } from "./comp_b";`

Hope this might be helpful.