# import or require React components dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to import / require components dynamically, but somehow when I do it React complains. The require function does find it, but React throws an error saying it is missing some functions 't' etc.. All of this in an electron app.

I have a wizard setup (that is working, but not so elegant I think), where each page has it's own layout and jsx component. If I'd like to add a new page, I don't want to manage x-number of files, and at the moment I have to due to the setup I have currently. **Below you can find what I want to achieve and what I'm doing now to achieve it**. If there are any suggestions, code smells or better options please let me know as I'm quite new to React and ES2015 (as I'm from a C# background).

**What I'm trying to achieve**

```
export default class WizardPageContainer extends Component {    
    // Constructor
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);        
    }

    // Render
    render() {
        const WizardPage = require(`./path/to/${this.props.step.id}`);

        return (
            <WizardPage step={this.props.step} />
        );
    }
}
```

**How I'm currently doing it** : which means I have to declare the imports / files first on top of the "WizardPageContainer" component.. Which means extra work and prone to errors/forgetting things. **I should add, this code is working now ok, but I don't think this is elegant/future proof**:

```
/* PAGES */
import WizardPage_Welcome from './pages/0.wizard.welcome';
import WizardPage_SystemCheck from './pages/1.wizard.systemCheck';
import WizardPage_SignIn from './pages/2.wizard.signIn';
import WizardPage_ExamCode from './pages/3.wizard.examCode';
import WizardPage_TakeExamination from './pages/4.wizard.takeExamination';
import WizardPage_Close from './pages/5.wizard.close';
const pages = [    
    WizardPage_Welcome,
    WizardPage_SystemCheck,
    WizardPage_SignIn,
    WizardPage_ExamCode,
    WizardPage_TakeExamination,
    WizardPage_Close
];
/*/********************************************************************///

/* ******************************************************************** */
/* COMPONENT */
export default class WizardPageContainer extends Component {    
    // Constructor
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);        
    }

    // Render
    render() {
        const WizardPage = pages[`${this.props.step.id}`];

        return (
            <WizardPage step={this.props.step} />
        );
    }
}
/*/********************************************************************///
```

Comment: Might have found a solution for this at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36678030/1155847. I will try this out and reporty back or close the question if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is about the "default". i have problem like this. Can you check this code;
https://github.com/robeio/robe-react-admin/blob/master/src/app/HasAuthorization.jsx#L10

Also you can check the example usage;
https://github.com/robeio/robe-react-admin/blob/master/src/app/HasAuthorization.jsx#L26

Comment: so using "importComponent" should to the trick in stead or using "require" or "import" if I understand your suggestion correctly?

Comment: you use like this;
importComponent(require("your path"))

Comment: thanks, with that tip I found a solution which I will explain in more detail.

Comment: ps @Hasan could you explain what this ".default" actually is or does? Is it the .default from export class default or is it something react, or from javascript itself? This would help the explenation I think.

Comment: @YvesSchelpe it's about ES6.

Comment: When you use module.export it assign your code as root.
For example;
   module.export = {example:"hello"}
when you import this code, you will get same code.
but in ES6 export is not working like that.
For example;
  export default  {example:"hello"}
when you import this code you will get same code. But if you use require instead of  import than you will get like this;
 { default :  {example:"hello"} }
it means in ES6 code wrapped by some rules.

Comment: @YvesSchelpe
Also you can check webpack configuration For example:

https://github.com/robeio/robe-react-ui

Answer (score 1):

Your `const pages`  needs to be an object, not an array.

You can see a working version I made of this here:
https://github.com/Frazer/meteor-react-nav/blob/master/lib/jsx/App.jsx

Comment: I should maybe add that consty pages code is working correctly for me now. But that I simply think it isn't elegant enough, as I'm loading the steps in memory from a json config and just want to look up the jsx pages at runtime. Now I basically do these things twice, with import statements and the const pages object as well as with the json file I have (not included in demo code).

Comment: so you are trying to find a way to do the imports and create the const pages using the data from the json file?

Comment: yes, I come from .Net / Java background where these things in building up UI's / wizards or menu's are trivial, with config files or other - e.g. provided by db queries etc... Maybe it's something that's considered not done, or bad practice in here? But yes, basically I recieve data, say in json, which holds names of specific parts which I then load (or search for) in the file system and then load up via a require and store in a const. That's maybe the plan - really dynamic, on the fly.

Comment: I wonder if there is a library that does what you are describing, if not, it sounds like a worthwhile project.

Comment: I wonder as well, I didn't find one to date - hence my question - but will look for it in the coming weeks when I'm back in #researchmode :)

Comment: Hi Yves,  I managed to almost make this dynamic here:  https://github.com/Frazer/react-nav  The src/Pages.js needs to export all the components I want, and then you can see how they are handled dynamically in src/Nav.js  and src/App.js - I hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score -5):

Best advice: Use Webpack to handle your imports, it's way more efficient than we could ever be.